Question on the density of states on a $d$-dimensional box $L$ sized
The teacher went through the theory on how to find the density of states of a quantum particule on a $d$-dimensional box of side $L$, spin $J$ and hamiltonian $H=\alpha |\vec{p}|^s$ where $\alpha, s$ are positive constants.
What confuses me: He then used the volume of an hypersphere of radius $R$ to find the number of states, something that to my knowledge, is completely unrelated, so I'm asking for some proof of the formula or some intuition behind using it.
He used the following:
$$\phi(\epsilon)=\frac{V_{hypersphere}(R)}{2^d}$$
It looks so pulled-out-of-thin-air.
Another question: and then for some reason the radius of the hypersphere $R$ is just $\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2}$ where $\vec{k}=\frac{\pi}{L}\vec{n}$? How is that expression the radius of the hypotetical hypersphere?

Your question is not clear. What is $\phi$? In any case, have you checked other material other than your lecture notes? The derivation is standard textbook treatment.

@TobiasFünke my bad $\phi$ is the number of states such that it's derivative is the density of states. But I cant find it on no book I try to look onto

even Wikipedia has a (brief) derivation, and also here on Physics SE there should be threads regarding this.

@TobiasFünke well I can't find it, I've found link and link 2 but none talk about the formula? Thus, my question is not only centered on that but as well on understanding how to find the radius of the hypersphere. Maybe you could post the link if you've found it, and no, there are not any posts here about it, or at least I can't find them.

Sorry, (it seems) I cannot quite follow what you mean and what you're asking for. Perhaps someone else can help. In any case, I think you should edit the question and add more relevant details or add what you've tried so far.

"But he then used the volume of an hypersphere of radius R to find the number of states for some reason?" This is not really a question, despite ending with a question mark... But, in any case, what shape do you think regions of constant $H$ describe? For example, $H=p^2$ being constant describes a sphere in three dimensions... so...

@hft I think it's quite clear that my intention to that phrase is express my surprise on how you can apply the volume of radius R to find something (to my knowledge) unrelated like the number of states. On any case I'll edit it to try to make it clearer.

@TobiasFünke there's literally no more details relevant, but I guess I'll try editing it

Your intention is not clear. You need to clarify what you are asking about.

@hft what do you mean? I have just edited it with the 2 doubts I have? How can I be more clear?

@Ivy Are you trying to find the density of states with respect to energy, or the number of states less than or equal to the energy, or something else?

I don't know how to explain to you how you can be more clear. Your question has been closed, so it can not be answered. But anyways, consider the volume of momentum space at a fixed magnitude of momentum. How would you describe that volume?

I give it one more try: I think the reason your question was voted to be closed and is downvoted (I did neither, because I thought you could improve the question in editing what you've tried) is that you seem (for whatever reason) to resist to look at the standard textbook examples of the derivation, where it should become more than clear where a "hypersphere" and a "radius" enters. And as I said, and you've found yourself, even Wikipedia has the derivation you are looking for. Without further clarification on what exactly the problem is, no one here could provide help.
